# Problems using transitions in WP8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, transition

I am currently developing a little app containing a list of entries. Nothing special so far. I use a `ListView` to display the entries and add an entrance transition. The following listing shows the xaml so far (this works as expected):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">        
  <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
      <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
    </TransitionCollection>
  </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>        
</ListView>
```

So far so easy, but when I try to replace the default `ItemsPanelTemplate` the transition is no longer working. I tried the following variations but without success:

```
<!--option 1-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

<!--option 2-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>

<!--option 3-->
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromVerticalOffset="100"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

None of these options work as expected. There simply is no transition, the entries only appear in place. I really don´t get why this doesn´t work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Christoph

Comment: Copied this thread to the msdn forum. I will repost their answer here as soon as the problem is solved. For so long here a link to the [msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8b6cb644-c15a-4076-bca2-a519fc9ba4a7/problems-using-transitions-in-listview-in-wp81-app?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: @BrunoLemos Hi, unfortunatly I haven´t got any solutions from the forum. A moderator there was able to reproduce the issue and wanted to further investigate it. But I didn´t get a fix or a workaround so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug with EntranceThemeTransition & ItemsSource. The binding gets applied together or just after the animation. Because EntranceThemeTransition just happens once, it thinks that it already executed and disables it.

A workaround is to add the items in the code behind. See code below:
[How to make EntranceThemeTransition works on a Custom Panel & ItemsSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635177/how-to-make-entrancethemetransition-works-on-a-custom-panel-itemssource)

Hope it helps.
This bug needs to be reported to the internal team. If you know how to, please do it.